# Get a reference to Xib File

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom table section header loaded from my tableSectionHeader.xib file through the following method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableSectionHeader", bundle: nil)
    discoverTableView.registerNib(nib, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "TableSectionHeader")

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("TableSectionHeader") as? TableSectionHeader {
    return cell
}
```

I want to have a variable table section header based on content so I need to get a reference to my xib file (which is assigned to tableSectionHeader.swift where my IBOutlets such as postImage, postDescription gets declared).

For example, I want to do something like this...

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {

    // get a reference to xib,
    return xibref.postImage.frame.height + xibref.postDescriptionLabel.frame.height

}
```

Thanks,

Note. I dont want to implement estimatedRowHeight because of the apprent "bug" that causes the tableView to jump as described in this post. I did it that way and encoutered that glitch without being able to fix it other than implementing the height manually
[UITableView with dynamic cell heights jumping when scrolling up after reloading cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440874/uitableview-with-dynamic-cell-heights-jumping-when-scrolling-up-after-reloading)

Comment: So you mean you want to instantiated the XIB and keep a sizing instance...

Comment: Yes. So I cant get the variables inside my xib file such as font size, frame size, labelTextcolor...etc. I could do it by looking into my xib file and see what they are, but that means if I change the height or something inside xib, I will have to change the code which is not very nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register the NIB in `viewDidLoad`, and at the same time you can instantiate the NIB and store the view instance in an instance variable, `xibref`. Then you can simplify your `viewForHeaderInSection` and your existing code in `heightForHeaderInSection` might work.

Note that in `heightForHeaderInSection` you may need to actually set an image / text into the view instance and ask it to layout in order to get the correct height from it.

Comment: I am not sure how to instantiate the Nib. Would you mind share some light? When I do         let nib = UINib(nibName: "TableSectionHeader", bundle: nil) as! TableSectionHeader, it says this cast will always fail. So I am not sure what would be the correct way. (TableSectionHeader contains all my IBOutlets and is connected to the Xib file). I have been working on story board alot more than xib files. Thanks

Comment: you need to use `instantiateWithOwner:options:`