# UITableView estimatedRowHeight changes its offset when reloaded

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, ios9

I am using autoLayout for my tableViewCell in StoryBoard, because I want to have variable height for rows based on the text.

Now in the viewDidLoad

I am using these lines of code

self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 310;

Now if i scroll tableView and then i reload it. It causes the tableView to set it offset (not sure why). Please see the image below (the white area above image) after reloading table view.

[image]

Comment: you forgot the image

Comment: put `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`

Comment: Even so, there might be an issue with iOS 8 devices. check out this question and its answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8640409/how-to-keep-uitableview-contentoffset-after-calling-reloaddata

Comment: Not getting the issue you are having with the provided screenshot.

Comment: Thanks maharoof for the link. i think i need to scroll the table view to the top before reloading tableview.

Answer (score -1):

Add this code in your viewDidLoad

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```