# Glitch in UITableView when UIBarButtonItem is animated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uibarbuttonitem

I use the second right bar button item as an indicator when there is a successful CloudKit sync. However, if the tableView is held in scroll (with items now under the navigation bar) when the indicator appears, the tableView bounces in sync with the animation. This does not happen if the user is not interacting with the tableView.

Here is a GIF demonstrating the effect.

[image: Animated screenshot]

The other `UIBarButtonItem`s are set up in the storyboard. The one for my iCloud sync indicator is set up in code in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
var cloudIndicator = UIImageView()
cloudIndicator.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25)
cloudIndicator.contentMode = .center
cloudIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
// Get existing right bar button item which was set up in storyboard
var rightButtonItems = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems ?? []
let customButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: cloudIndicator)
rightButtonItems.append(customButtonItem)
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = rightButtonItems
```

This is the method that animates the cloud sync indicator:

```
func cloudLabelImageAlert(_ image: UIImage, tintColor: UIColor = .darkGray) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.cloudIndicator.alpha = 0
        self.cloudIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        self.cloudIndicator.tintColor = tintColor
        self.cloudIndicator.image = image
        // Animate icon appearing
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: [], animations: {
            self.cloudIndicator.alpha = 1
            self.cloudIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { didFinish in
            // Animate icon disappearing
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, delay: 2.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1.0, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: [], animations: {
                self.cloudIndicator.alpha = 0
                self.cloudIndicator.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
            }, completion: nil)
        })
    }
)
```

Presumably this problem relates to the frame of the image view changing during the animation, but it seems strange that it only happens while the tableView is being interacted with.

Is there a way to prevent this happening, or a better way to animate an image view as a bar button item?

---

**Edit**

Thanks to advice in the comments, it turns out this is due to reloading the tableview and nothing to do with the animation.

I found the problematic code, which is called after a CloudKit sync:

```
if let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
    self.tableView.deselectRow(at: index, animated: true)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+1) {
        self.tableView.reloadData() // This is delayed as it was causing problems with autoselection (e.g. after coming from Spotlight or notification)
        let image = UIImage(named: "cloudTick")!
        self.cloudLabelImageAlert(image, tintColor: self.colors[0])
    }
} else {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    let image = UIImage(named: "cloudTick")!
    self.cloudLabelImageAlert(image, tintColor: self.colors[0])
}
```

Commenting out the `self.tableview.reloadData()` lines stopped the glitch but the animation continued as expected.

I need to update the data at this point for the user. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Because he tableView is reloading its cells when syncing.

Comment: @Carpsen90 Thanks. I will check that, but this is only triggered after a successful sync (not at a reload, though I will check this), and the glitch seems to be in time with the animation for the duration of the animation. Surely a reload would just be a single point in time?

Comment: Could you share code where you use `cloudLabelImageAlert`? Would be helpful.

Comment: @PranavKasetti I will share this later once I’m back at my computer. Thanks

Comment: @Chris Are you sure your not invoking `cloudLabelImageAlert(image:, tintColor:)` method while loading new table cells ?

Comment: I have edited the question. Carpsen90, Pranav and Sharkes were right - I was reloading the tableview data and this was the actual cause of the problem. I would be happy to accept an answer and award the bounty accordingly.

Comment: Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8640409/8289095) seems to provide some workarounds for this.

Comment: @Carpsen90 Question updated

Comment: @PranavKasetti Question updated

Comment: @SharkesMonken Question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned on the comment section, you where probably invoking `cloudLabelImageAlert(image:, tintColor:)` method while loading new table cells.

About updating the data, i would suggest invoking table view `reloadData()` method after the cloud animation completes.

Comment: Thanks for this. You were absolutely right about it being the reloading of the tableView causing the glitch and not the animation at all!

Answer (score 2):

It seems for some mysterious reason your navigation bar is showing "large title" for a moment which leads to contentInset change of the tableView.
So try to manually disable large titles at all in viewDidLoad:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
     navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never
     navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. The large title is deliberate. The first movement in the gif is me scrolling the tableView manually. The jerky movement after that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i had somwhat similar glitch not same but for me it got fixed by putting self.automaticallyScrollInsets to false in viewDidLoad and while animating the imageView for hide and show in the final UIView.animate completion block i called reloadData(). Hope this helps and thanks !